# jQuery html injection from list without wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following quide in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and everything is great except I'm puzzled about injection part.

It's hard for me to understand what this exactly does:

```
$('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('body');
```

Well `appendTo()` is clear. But how it makes html out of JS array and how to remove wrapping? Can this be translated to group of simple commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That could be rewritten like so:

```
 var element = $('<ul/>');
 element.addClass('my-new-list').html(items.join(''));
 element.appendTo('body');
```

It's just creating a new element with the specified values and properties.

From [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) link, it is the `jQuery( html,props )` overload.

Comment: So instead of creating element i should select existing one?

Comment: @JackLeo HUH? what do you mean select existing one?

Comment: Yes I was right. I mean that I wanted to drop the wrapping. I did `$(items.join('')).appendTo('my-needed-place')`. It works. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This creates new `<ul>`, with class `my-new-list` and joins `items` variable. After that, it is all appended to body. It could be like

```
var ul = $('<ul/>')
ul.addClass('my-new-list');
ul.html(items.join(''));
ul.appendTo(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = $('<ul/>');          //var elem = document.createElement("ul");
elem.addClass('my-new-list');   //elem.className = 'my-new-list';
elem.html(items.join(''));      //elem.innerHTML = items.join('');
elem.appendTo('body');          //document.body.append(elm);
```